# How many listeners in a Bounded Context can be subscribed to a specific domain event?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a doubt regarding the best strategy for how many listeners can be subscribed to a specific domain event.

Say that we have a domain event called `UserWasCreated` being published when a new user is created in the Bounded Context A. Say that we have another Bounded Context B subscribed to that event in which we have to do many tasks such as: sending an email, persisting certain information of the user and pushing the user info to an external service (i.e.a CRM).

My question is, how many listeners should I have for that event within the same Bounded Context?

I've seen IDDD book from Vernon having just one listener per event like this `UserWasCreatedListener`. But that listener has just one specific responsibility while in my example there are different tasks involved.

Would it make sense having one listener per event-task? So following the example we would have:

```
UserWasCreated_NotifyByEmailListener
UserWasCreated_NotifyCrmListener
UserWasCreated_PersistUserListener
```

If it does make sense, how would you name these listeners? Is there any scalability problem because of creating too many listeners?

Comment: I'd have as many listeners as unrelated operations.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer directly related to how many listeners (subscribers) there can be for an event: 0 to *N*

I like to distinguish between the following types of events:

- Domain
- Event Sourcing
- Messaging (System)

The reason is that they have different meanings and would, in many cases, carry different data.

Back to your question.  You are describing a process.  A process is typically started by some *command* or, as in your case, *event*.  A process may be driven in on of two ways:

- Orchestration
- Choreography

When messages are **choreographed** they are very *reactive*.  The means that one event leads to another.  In your case you could have:

- UserCreatedEvent -> PersistUserHandler (subscriber) -> UserPersistedEvent
- UserPersistedEvent -> CrmListener (subscriber) -> CrmUserCreatedEvent
- CrmUserCreatedEvent -> EMailNotifier (subscriber) -> UserNotifiedEvent

These work OK if it is a rather simple, sequential, flow.  When you need user intervention, such as reviewing items, or parallel processing things tend to get hairy.

*Orchestraion*, on the other hand, makes use of a **process manager** that keeps the state of the process and interacts with the various atomic services.

In your case you could have a `UserRegistrationProcess` that would be instantiated when required.  In your case perhaps on the user creation.  Another approach is to kick off the process and have *it* include the user creation.  Your `UserRegistrationProcess` would be the subscriber to the various events.  But instead of the various listeners *reacting* to arbitrary events they only service the relevant commands.

- Start Process
- Process sends `CreatedUserCommand` to the UserEndpoint (BC)
- Process receives `UserCreatedEvent` from the UserEndpoint (BC)
- Process sends `CreateCrmUserCommand` to the CrmEndpoint (BC)
- Process receives `CrmUserCreatedEvent` from the CrmEndpoint (BC)
- Process sends the `SendEMailCommand` to the EMailEndpoint (infrastructure)
  `Process receives the`EMailSentEvent` fromt the EMailEndpoint (infrastructure)
- Terminate Process

In this way the **process layer** becomes a bounded context in its own right.

I prefer orchestration since you always have a view on the progress of an process.